# Pop Menu items with different color

Tags: android, colors, popup

On `Button Click` am showing `Pop up Menu` with 3 `items`, But all `items` are in Black Color (Item Text Color).But I want each item with different color.

I tried by applying style:

```
 <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/blue_text</item>
 <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/bottom_green</item>
```

But It will show all items in blue color.

Is it possible to show Pop Up Menu items with different color?

Please suggest me.

Thank you.

Comment: @Clara let me try this..

Comment: Ok..I will Check something else instead of popup menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
After inflating your popup menu, For each and every item you can set custom title having customise colour.

**Here is an example:**

```
MenuItem customMenuItem;
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(SampleActivity.this, YourOverFlowButton, Gravity.LEFT);    

popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu_item, popup.getMenu());
SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Third Item");
s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, s.length(), 0);
customMenuItem.setTitle(s);
```